# Count distinct items between start date and end date in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I have these two tables:

**Table 1**

```
| EventCode | StartDate |  EndDate  | Client |
|   13400   | 1/12/2014 | 5/12/2014 |   ABC  |
|   13400   | 6/12/2014 | 8/12/2014 |   ABC  |
|   15600   | 3/12/2014 | 5/12/2014 |   ABC  |
```

**Table 2**

```
| EventCode | Client | SignUpDate | Agent |
|   13400   |   ABC  |  2/12/2014 | AG001 |
|   13400   |   ABC  |  2/12/2014 | AG001 |
|   13400   |   ABC  |  3/12/2014 | AG002 |
|   15600   |   ABC  |  4/12/2014 | AG002 |
|   15600   |   ABC  |  4/12/2014 | AG004 |
|   15600   |   ABC  |  5/12/2014 | AG002 |
|   13400   |   ABC  |  7/12/2014 | AG003 |
```

I need to join the two tables `WHERE Table2.SignUpDate BETWEEN Table1.StartDate AND Table1.EndDate`, then I need a **distinct** count of Agents from Table 2, to get how many distinct persons did sales for every event, like the one below:

```
| EventCode | StartDate |  EndDate  | Client |  CountOfDistinctAgents |
|   13400   | 1/12/2014 | 5/12/2014 |   ABC  |           2            | //(AG001, AG002)
|   13400   | 6/12/2014 | 8/12/2014 |   ABC  |           1            | //(AG003)
|   15600   | 3/12/2014 | 5/12/2014 |   ABC  |           2            | //(AG002, AG004)
```

But I am having trouble getting the above output because I need to do this in **MS ACCESS 2003**.
Please help me.

This is my old code, but it doesn't count the DISTINCT agents.

```
SELECT tmp.[Event Code], eb.CampaignLN, eb.StartDate, eb.EndDate, COUNT(*) AS HeadCount
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT [Event Code], Campaign, [Signup Date], [Agent Id] FROM [Main Table2]) AS tmp 
INNER JOIN qryGetEventBookings AS eb ON (tmp.[Signup Date] BETWEEN CDATE(eb.StartDate) AND  
CDATE(eb.EndDate)) AND (eb.CampaignLN=tmp.Campaign) AND (eb.LocationCode=tmp.[Event Code])
GROUP BY tmp.[Event Code], eb.CampaignLN, eb.StartDate, eb.EndDate;
```

I greatly appreciate all of your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "COUNT(DISTINCT [Agent Id])" work in MS Access or not? In SQL Server that would be solution, but I do not know all Access limitations.

Comment: Unfortunately no, Access does not support that Count(Distinct *). :(

Answer (score 3):

To count the distinct agents, you need to use a subquery (because MS Access does not support `count(distinct)`).  The result is something like this:

```
SELECT [Event Code], COUNT(*) AS NumAgents
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT m.EventCode, eb.Agent
      FROM  [Main Table2] as m JOIN
            qryGetEventBookings eb
            ON eb.CampaignLN = m.Campaign AND eb.LocationCode = m.[Event Code] AND
               eb.SignUpDate BETWEEN m.StartDate AND m.EndDate
     ) AS tmp 
GROUP BY [Event Code];
```

Comment: I managed to use the concept but it's missing the details I was looking for which I eventually figured out. But hey, thank you very much! Really big help. :)